# unix unzip utility: is there a way to give the extracted folder a different name than the zip file name?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I can do the command:

```
 unzip  some-zip.zip
```

and it will produce a some-zip folder.

I don't want a default folder name, but to create my own.  Nor do I want to do a mv after.

I don't see a command line option to handle this.  Can I accomplish this easily with redirection (if indeed no command line option)?   If so, will that work efficiently for a fairly large zip file (52 MB)?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the zip file has a directory component on the files in the archive I don't know of a way to do this with the command line tools.

Comment: My unzip has a `-d exdir` option that is "an  optional  directory  to which to extract files"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unzip file.zip -d destination_folder
```

Comment: No worries, I do that all the time.